# Why is it reasonable to recognize solutions to Dirac Equation as electron and positron?

Tags: fermions, antimatter, dirac-equation

I'm reading Griffiths' book and when it claims the first two components of plane wave solution to massive Dirac equation as electron and the “holes” of other two components as positron, it does not seem natural to me... Am I missing some crucial idea?

Comment: It applies to any fermionic field, including electrons.

Comment: But not to photons.

Comment: Google Dirac hole theory for an explanation.